# Tensorflow: Gradient through composition of networks

Tags: python, tensorflow

Suppose we have two independent CNNs `A(x)`, `B(z)` and define their composition `B(A(x))` in *Tensorflow*:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape)
A = CNN1.inference(x)
B = CNN2.inference(A)
y = tf.nn.softmax(B)
```

Now we want the derivative `dy/dx` for some output neuron `j` and write:

```
dy = tf.gradients(y[j], x)[0]
```

**Will this calculate the gradients correctly?**

Let us perform gradient ascent on `x` starting from a random point in `X` space:

```
x_val = np.random.normal(shape)
for _ in range(100):
    x_val += sess.run(dy, feed_dict={x: x_val})
```

**Does this loop actually perform the gradient ascent correctly?**

Comment: I think this question has better chance of being answered on stats.stackexchange.com or cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: In the loop in the last snippet, you probably want to initialize `x_val` as a regular array with NumPy instead of a TF tensor. Otherwise (if it works, I'm not sure if you can pass tensors as values in `feed_dict`) it will create new ops in the graph on each iteration.

Comment: Anyway I _think_ your code is correct, have you actually tried it? You can `run` both `dy` and `y` to check if the value really grows (on the `j` component, of course).

Comment: I will try it and check if component j grows. Also will initialize it as a numpy array instead, makes sense.

Comment: Updated the question to include numpy array as per jdehesa's suggestion.

Comment: Running the loop makes the value of the `j:th` output grow. If I want the gradient of the composition, is `tf.graidents(.)` the correct function to use?

Comment: Composition `B(A(X))` in the context of CNN is no different than connecting `A`'s outputs to `B`'s inputs. This is exactly the same thing you do when you connect successive layers of a CNN to each other. In other words, any deep CCN is a composition of CNNs. There is nothing special about it. Regular `tf.gradients` will work just fine.